# How we retrieve data from realm locally in UITableView?

Tags: swift, realm, ios11

I downloaded all data in local db. I want that when internet is not available the local is retrieve automatically.

```
for result in data {
self.dataSource.append(ModelData(value: result))
}
try! Global.APP_REALM?.write(){
Global.APP_REALM?.add(self.dataSource, update: true)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this one its working fine

```
if !Connectivity.isConnectedToInternet() {
dataSource.removeAll()
let Object = Global.APP_REALM?.objects(Hameotology.self)
                for result in hameotologyObject! {
                    self.dataSource.append(ModelData(value: result))
                }
                tableViewTest.reloadData()
}
```